# How can I implement scrum if management won't commit resources?

Tags: project-management, scrum, management

I want to try to apply scrum to a project.  For the purposes of my question, let's assume that there are no other problems I'm trying to solve; I just want to practice scrum.

Over the summer we're hoping to have 3 full-time developers (two working half-time on the project) and 1 or 2 interns.

Unfortunately, management insists that they must be able to pull resources at a moment's notice whenever they deem it necessary, and they refuse to commit personnel for even a 2-week sprint.  I think at most they will pull two people from the project, leaving at least one senior engineer and two interns on the project.  I still want to try scrum, but how can I work around this?  Do I just convince the other team members to try it with me, and do it without management's blessing?

I know the foundation of scrum is that team members must be permitted to work uninterrupted for the duration of a sprint, but is there a way to work around this if management will not guarantee the resources?  Certainly in the real world people must get sick or leave the team in the middle of the sprint once in a while.  How does the scrum team deal with this and track its acceleration in a meaningful way?

My idea at this point is to do the following:

1. Implement scrum with 2-week sprints but only allocate resources that are less likely to be pulled. Others may work on the project, but not necessarily as part of the scrum team's development crew.  (Maybe they focus on testing or documentation, or pull work items from the project backlog instead of the TODO list.)
2. If we are interrupted after a sprint has started, make a note, reallocate resources and tasks, and restart the sprint with the remaining resources.
3. If the team was rarely interrupted, or if the sprint was usually interrupted only a day or two from the beginning or end of the sprint, try to use that data to convince management that scrum would not be that disruptive to the other projects.  (This is assuming we can demonstrate that scrum worked at all for the duration of the summer.)

Is it likely this will work, or is it not really worth the effort to try to implement scrum if we cannot guarantee that the team won't be interrupted?  Are there any other practical solutions to this problem?

Comment: What makes you think scrum is going to solve the fundamental problem of insufficient resources?  The phrase "blood from a turnip" comes to mind.

Comment: Are shorter sprints possible?

Comment: @DanPichelman: Are shorter sprints desirable?  I can see getting to the point where there's more cognitive and administrative overhead than there is actual work getting done.

Comment: You have a hammer (scrum). Your problems require a screwdriver and a tape measure (insufficient resources and non-dedicated resources).  You can't just use a hammer to measure things and screw stuff in, you need to find a screwdriver and tape measure. This requires solving those core problems -- not patching work arounds constantly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey At some point certainly not.  I was thinking if the sprints were smaller/more granular, there might be less damage to the project when resources get removed.

Comment: @enderland: if you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail, you know?

Comment: @enderland: I think your analogy is bad. The OP doesn't have a hammer, they have a hammer and a screwdriver and a saw, and sometimes somebody steals the hammer. While the core problem (stealing the hammer) can't be solved by scrum, scrum can make the problem more visible so that maybe the person stealing the hammer will realize the impact they are having on productivity.

Comment: @DanPichelman 2 weeks may already be too short but I think it's a reasonable starting point, as arbitrary lengths of time go. I've also toyed with the idea of allocating a resource for only half the sprint.

Comment: Convince your manager to stop pulling resources... That's the only way.  Scrum isn't going to fix that.

Comment: Scrum won't put a project on-schedule.  It will just let you know that it is behind schedule early and makes it much easier to dump features early to hit dates.

Comment: @rob: seems you don't want to hear it, but your problems have *nothing* to do with scrum. Seeking scrum-specific advice for a such a problem and ignoring experienced people like Rob Harvey won't bring you any further.

Comment: @StevenBurnap thanks for pointing out that redefinition of "on time." That's how I understood it as well, but there's also the notion of team acceleration that I found appealing in `Scrum: The Art of Doing Twice the Work in Half the Time`. Maybe I'm a sucker, but I want to give it a try.

Comment: @DocBrown okay, I've reframed the question. Let's assert that scrum won't solve any of the project's problems. Given the premise that I want to try scrum on the project anyway, what's a reasonable way to move forward if management won't promise not to pull a resource in the middle of a sprint?

Comment: Scrum isn't worthless by any means, and it can solve problems.  But it isn't a silver bullet and does require buy-in to some key tenets.  Not changing team members midsprint is a biggy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I think the question isn't "how can scrum solve this problem?" but rather "can scrum work in the presence of this problem?". Your comments seem to be more about the former. Valid points, but I think a little off-topic.

Comment: @BryanOakley: There isn't any material difference between those two questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there is absolutely a difference, but if I'm not able to convince you of that, I still must not be communicating it clearly enough.  Anyway, Bryan has provided a helpful answer. Thanks for your part in helping me clarify my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scrum doesn't know nor care anything about management issues. It's a way to organize  your work, and to make problems visible so they can be fixed. Scrum can't fix your problem, but it at least can make it visible.

Start doing scrum, making any assumptions you want about resource availability. Plan according to that. Follow the scrum practices. When a resource gets yanked from the project, note that as a distraction and carry on -- this is really no different than if someone got sick, quit, or is just having a bad day. The rest of the team has to carry on and try to finish (but *not* by working extra  hours!)

At the end of a sprint, you now have evidence of how much you've been able to accomplish. Hopefully you'll start to see a pattern emerge: you cannot effectively plan with a constantly changing team. You'll (hopefully!) also see that when you can go two weeks without losing anyone, you are able to complete a predictable amount of work.

In short: do scrum, and let it do what it does best, which is to expose impediments early, and give you a framework for dealing with the impediments.

Comment: +1 for scrum giving management some evidence that their usage of resources is a problem. Nothing like cold, hard numbers to expose problems. You could also provide constructive criticism on how Scrum may assist in planning on a larger scale which could help with their resource allocation issues.